# Clicking a button to change img src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been working on this for a while now and have been scouring this website for the answer to my fix but can't find it. I'm making a blackjack game, and I have been using jQuery to change the image source.

here is the html:

```
<button id="startgame" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Start Game</button>
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <p class="text-center">Player</p>
  <div id='d1pfirstcard' class="col-xs-2">
    <p id="playerside" class="">card one</p>
    <img id="pfirstcard" class="scaled-card" src="Deck/Playing Cards/PNG-cards-1.3/back of card.png">
```

here is the function:

```
$('#startgame').click(function() {
  $('#pfirstcard').attr('src', "Deck/Playing Cards/PNG-cards-1.3/2_of_clubs.png");
});
```

I have also tried:

```
$('#startgame').on('click', function() {
  $('#pfirstcard').attr('src', "Deck/Playing Cards/PNG-cards-1.3/2_of_clubs.png");
```

here is my header:

```
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- external CSS file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<!-- external js file -->
<script src="application.js"></script>

<title> Black Jack 21</title>
```

here is more of my code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
let suits = ["Spades", "Clubs", "Hearts", "Diamonds"];
let values = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"];
let theDeck = new Array();

let playerHandValue = 0;
let dealerHandValue = 0;

 $('#startgame').click(function(){
  $('#pfirstcard').attr('src',"https://placekitten.com/g/500/500");
});
```

Note that I have more code below so that's why it's not closed with an additional
     });

Comment: What you have should work. Do you have multiple elements with the same `#pfirstcard` id attribute?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1xgbz5xj/ - the code above, by itself, works with no problem (watch the image element in the browser dev tools - its src gets changed when you click). You haven't said what's going wrong, but assuming that this isn't working somehow? Are the image URLs definitely valid? If so then you need to provide extra context about the situation because there's not enough info here to say what the problem could be.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no, each image source has it's own id "psecondcard" etc. same with each div having the "d2psecondcard" etc.

Comment: Share the page where you have this code, so that we will get complete idea about problem.

Comment: In which case what you have should work - assuming paths etc. are correct. You can see this in @ADyson's example fiddle. We need a more complete example of your code which demonstrates the problem in order to help you. Have you checked that the `click()` event is even being fired? Are the elements added dynamically after load by JS?

Comment: try to print something on browser  console on button  click? this will make sure selector $('#startgame') is working , other wise your code look fine

Comment: @ADyson yea i see it getting changed in the jsfiddle, when I click on the button in my browser (i'm using brackets) the "back_of_card.pgn" is not being changed, it stays there. but when I open up the console on my webpage and click the button it's not being changed. when I click "start game" it remains blank... i'll update the post.

Comment: @Balwant I did the console.log("test"); and looked at the console and nothing came up

Comment: try to replace  $('#startgame')  with $('button')  in case if there is only one button element there  or can you share your page?

Comment: have you wrapped `$('#startgame').click` inside a `document.ready` block to ensure it doesn't run until the page is ready and all elements are present? (otherwise, if it's placed before your HTML in the page, it will try and attach itself to an element which doesn't exist yet). Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/1xgbz5xj/1/ (in the previous version I cheated and had JSFiddle do that part for me!). Perhaps if you rearrange the question in your code so it more accurately reflects your page's real HTML structure, we could see more clearly what might be wrong.

Comment: @ADyson yes i have wrapped it in a     document.ready, also I added more of my code in the post including my header

Comment: I updated and everything seems to be working fine now, I'm not sure what happened or what I did, but it seems to be working the way that I want it to! thanks a lot for all of you guys' help and patience!

Comment: Please don't add "(Solved)" to your title